# How can I use isActive value OUTSIDE OF THE NAVLINK itself? ( React router 6+)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have jsx like this

```
<div className="sidebar__link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <NavLink
              end
              to="/"
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? "selected" : ""
              }
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </div>
<div className="sidebar__link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <NavLink
              end
              to="/profile"
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? "selected" : ""
              }
            >
              User Profile
            </NavLink>
          </div>
```

And I want to use the isActive to change the icon. I tried this

```
<div className="sidebar__link">
            <i class={`${isActive?"fa-solid":"fa-regular"} fa-circle`}></i>
            <NavLink
              end
              to="/"
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? "selected" : ""
              }
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </div>
```

Code above returns error, the isActive isnt defined. So anyone know how to use the isActive from NavLink to use it outside the NavLink?